# Change ListView Template Programmatically [Android]

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Basically, what I want to do is change the ListView template (layout) item based on a parameter in Android. For example:

```
if(a == true){
    ListView.setItemLayout(LayoutA);
}else{
    ListView.setItemLayout(LayoutB);
```

This would allow me to have two different item layouts in one list, so I could have a Image based layout and a text based layout, all depending on whether or not a parameter is fulfilled or not. I've already implemented a image based layout, but wanted to know if this was possible, and if so, how it would be done.

The project I'm working on: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/tanishq-dubey/RedditMaterialReader)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create two row layout files and can inflate one as per your condition. for example,

```
if(a == true) {
    // inflate first one
}
else {
    // inflate second one
}
```

And put a conditional logic for that view.

Comment: See, I tried that, but it leads to errors, such as items in the view repeating.